# Excel - Update difference in data between 2 spreadsheets automatically

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

this is my first time posting a question here, please let me know if there's anything I am doing wrongly!

I would like to ask if it is possible to automatically update a excel spreadsheet grabbing data from multiple spreadsheet after comparing its differences. For example:

`My own spreadsheet
 Name     Value 
 John     123
 Smith    456
 Jane     789`

I'll send this said spreadsheet to these 3 persons and they will update their individual values and send the spreadsheet back to me. Is there a way I can update these values automatically even after I delete the spreadsheet they have sent to me, retaining only the master copy that I have? My main concern other than this is the data being replaced or 'unupdated' by mistake.

For example
John changes his value to 888 and sends it back so his copy will be
`Name   Value
John    888
Smith   456
Jane    789`

Jane changes her value to 333 and sends it back with
`Name   Value
John    123
Smith   456
Jane    333`

My end result after automatically updating has to be
`My updated spreadsheet
Name    Value
John    888
Smith   456
Jane    333`

After updating John's value, I go on to update Jane's using her spreadsheet that she sent, but it must not replace John's value BACK to 123 because I have already updated his value to 888. These spreadsheets they sent to me will also be removed afterwards but the updated values in my own copy must be kept intact. Is there a workaround for this case? If possible I would like to limit it within Excel functions, otherwise I am open to suggestions using other tools.

So far I have only been able to establish a check for difference between 2 sheets (I copy the spreadsheet people send me into a separate spreadsheet into my own workbook to compare) using `B2<>Sheet2!B2` as a conditional formatting rule if I am comparing B2. It highlights that the cell values are different but that is all I have been able to do with my limited knowledge. I looked around regarding VLOOKUP but I am not too sure if it does what I want (I am a newbie at Excel)

Sorry if my explanation is not very clear, thanks everyone in advance for the help!

Comment: Your explanation is fine. Where is your code? I only see a list of requirements.

Comment: You can't permanently update a spreadsheet using formulas alone.

Comment: @Jeeped Hey, so far I have only been able to establish a check for difference between 2 sheets (I copy the spreadsheet people send me into a separate spreadsheet into my own workbook to compare) using `B2<>Sheet2!B2` as a conditional formatting rule if I am comparing B2. It highlights that the cell values are different but that is all I have been able to do with my limited knowledge. I looked around regarding VLOOKUP but I am not too sure if it does what I want (I am a newbie at Excel)

Comment: @TimWilliams Hello! Do you know of any way I can do it? Is it possible via python scripting to parse through the spreadsheets to compare the differences and update the cell data automatically?

Comment: You can use VBA/python/.NET or likely any other language you're familiar with.  Might the other users re-sort the data or add/remove rows while editing?  This type of update is not super-simple if you need to account for things like that.

Comment: @TimWilliams As far as I know they will not be resorting nor adding/removing rows. Just changing the 'values' column when required. What keywords should I be using to search on how to do this? I am a beginner in programming so I think this might be a good chance for me to learn as well. Thanks!

Comment: You need to know how to loop over the rows in your original sheet and reference the cells in the same positions in the other sheet(s).  If you find a difference, then update the sheet. To track whether a cell has already been updated, maybe store the previous value in a tracking sheet.  What if two users update the same cell though/  It's not clear who should "win" in that scenario.  I'm also assuming your actual data is more complex than your example.

Comment: Google-spreadsheet sounds like an easy answer to your problem, depending on what you do with the data and how you process it.

Comment: @TimWilliams Fortunately, there will not be a scenario where a cell is updated twice. When you mean storing the previous value, do you mean I should store John's modified '888' value in a tracking sheet? Sorry I do not really understand how it works, having a tracking sheet and check if it has already been updated and determining whether it should be updated again or not. How can this be done in terms of code logic?

Comment: @O.PAL Unfortunately I will not be able to access Google Spreadsheets as I am instructed the data to only exist on local standalone machines, thank you for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

My your definition, detecting a difference will show that Jane's change will look like she changed John to 123.  You can't magically know which is correct unless you build in history which is more work and more programming.  I suggest you use a single, shared sheet or something like an Access database on a shared drive somewhere.